# Regex pattern matching comma delimited values with spaces allowed around comma

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a Regex validator (Python 3.8) to accept strings like these:

```
foo
foo,bar
foo, bar
foo , bar
foo    ,      bar
foo, bar,foobar
```

This is what I have so far (but it matches only the first two cases):

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$|^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

However, when I add the whitespace match `\w`, it stops matching altogether:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+(\w+,\w+[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$|^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

What is the pattern to use (with explanation as to why my second pattern above is not matching).

Comment: I assume this is a purely academic exercise because judicious use of *split()* and *strip()* would solve this problem with ease. Also, you say you're writing a "validator" which begs the question "What constitutes an invalid string?"

Comment: @Stuart this is part of a Django project - so to an extent it is academic - in the sense that I **could** simply override the `save()` method and do my checks there - but I like the idea of abstracting and encapsulating validation in another class, so it can be used on other fields and other models too. Valid strings are strings that can be split by a delimiter into a list of alphanumeric tokens.

Comment: Therefore the string 'foo' would be considered invalid as there's no apparent delimiter - is that right?

Comment: I'm simplifying things a bit here - but a single alphanumeric string is the exception (bad choice of word), to the general rule I gave previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` matches `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` and it doesn't include whitespaces.

What you need is this regex:

```bash
^[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qtkNMh/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*`: Match a text starting with a letter followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\s*,\s*`: Match a comma optionally surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on both sides
  - `[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*`: Match a text starting with a letter followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `$`: End